# detect collision of two moving buttons in iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, collision-detection

I am using the below function to move two buttons on the screen

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished));
```

Now I want to detect the collision of those moving button.

So I want to know is there any event which is getting fired when the object is animating(moving).
Or where else can I place my condition of

```
CGRectIntersectsRect(,);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished));
```

is a "fire and forget" type animation.  You don't have access to the internals.  It's automatic.

If you need to do collision detection, you can use a 2D sprite library like Cocos2D or you can set up a timer to move and animate the buttons manually.

Comment: I sure did.  It says Cocos2D now, but it looks like some kind soul edited it for me.